# Ravel() on only two dimensions of a 3D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of shape `(182, 218, 182)`.

I'm trying to reorganize it such that it is size `(182, 39676)` - e.g., take each of the 182 slices of it and ravel() out each of those slices into one dimension, but still keep the slices separate.

I can think of a few ways of doing this with a loop, but it seems un-pythonic to make a loop in numpy. Anyone know if there's a method or parameter somewhere that'll do the trick?

Thanks!

Comment: Does `arr.reshape((182, -1))` not do what you want?  You could generalize this even more: `arr.reshape(arr.shape[0], -1)`

Comment: That works! I'm pretty unfamiliar with numpy so I didn't realize you could just do it with a simple reshape method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy
   # initialize a[182][218][182]
   a=numpy.reshape(a,(182,39676))
```

This reshape should do the work.